# access youtube analytics api via content manager account's client id

Tags: youtube-analytics-api, youtube-analytics

We have content manager account which has been granted to access to all channels we have. 
We do authorization procedure for each service accounts to get access tokens for analytics-API,
it works well, but it also demands when new channel is added.

Is it possible that issuing an access token via client id of content manager account, and use it to call API to access all channels that content manager account handles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can call api with id set 'contentOnwer==id_of_content_manager'. And it is able to access to all data from channels this account manages.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube api is channel + user based.  Each access token is authorized to access a single user + channel.

If you have five channels you will need to login five times and each access token you get back will have access to the single channel.

Comment: Thanks. ~ . I  just wanted to know if there is easier way